# Has a value of 0 for bit 1, what does it mean?

Tags: bit

For example for a 4 byte string of 0x00010203, what does bit 1 mean here? Does it refer to the bit 1 of '00', or '03'?

I would expect to check the bit 1 in the right most byte (which is '03'). Is it correct? What will be a clear description if I want to refer the bit 1 in '00' (the left most byte)?

Comment: You'll need to check the context to figure out whether it's little-endian or big-endian, 0-indexed or 1-indexed, or what. We can't tell you what convention whatever you're looking at is using.